# How to filter a table using multiple select2 boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am trying to filter a table using the class of the  and multiple select2 boxes.

**Table HTML**

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="kanban-event Austin">
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="csm-event Charlotte">
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cal-event Charlotte">
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cspo-event Austin">
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cal-event Raleigh">
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="kanban Charlotte">
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cspo-event Austin">
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="csm-event Charlotte">
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="safe-event Austin">
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cspo-event Raleigh">
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="csm-event Charlotte">
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="csm-event Raleigh">
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Select HTML**

```
<select id="location">
    <option value="all">All Locations ...</option>
    <option value="Austin">Austin, TX</option>
    <option value="Charlotte">Charlotte, NC</option>
    <option value="Raleigh">Raleigh, NC</option>
</select>

<select id="course">
    <option value="all">All Courses ...</option>
    <option value="csm">Certified Scrum Master (CSM)</option>
    <option value="cspo">Certified Scrum Product Owner (CSPO)</option>
    <option value="cal">Certified Agile Leadership (CAL)</option>
    <option value="safe">Scaled Agile Framework (SAFe&reg;)</option>
    <option value="kanban">Kanban</option>
</select>
```

**Current JS**

```
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery("#course").on("select2-selecting", function (evt) {
      // console.log(evt.val);
      // console.log(jQuery('#events-table tr:not(".'+evt.val+'-event")'));
      jQuery('#events-table tr').show();
      jQuery('#events-table thead tr').show();
      jQuery('#events-table tr:not(".'+evt.val+'-event")').hide();
      jQuery('#events-table thead tr').show();
      if (evt.val == '') {
        jQuery('#events-table tr').show();
        jQuery('#events-table thead tr').show();
      }
    });

    jQuery("#location").on("select2-selecting", function (evt) {
      // console.log(evt.val);
      // console.log(jQuery('#events-table tr:not(".'+evt.val+'")'));
      jQuery('#events-table tr').show();
      jQuery('#events-table thead tr').show();
      jQuery('#events-table tr:not(".'+evt.val+'")').hide();
      jQuery('#events-table thead tr').show();
      if (evt.val == '') {
        jQuery('#events-table tr').show();
        jQuery('#events-table thead tr').show();
      }
    });
});
```

The current JS allows filtering to the table but only handles a single filter at a time. I am wondering how can I make the selects work together for example having the CSM Events in Austin show and everything else hide?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5202jsax/6/

Comment: Please add jsfiddle, it would be good.

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik - Fiddle added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I can think of getting your selectors to work together (without changing too much code) is to:

1. Create two new css classes: "hidden-course" and "hidden-location"
2. When you want to hide/show table rows based on "course", you add/remove the "hidden-course" class INSTEAD of using .show()/.hide()
3. When you want to hide/show table rows based on "location", you add/remove the "hidden-location" class INSTEAD of using .show()/.hide()

The css for the new classes would look like this:

```
.hidden-course,
.hidden-location {
    display: none;
}
```

For example, if we ignore the activity in the table head (thead) element, the "course" function would become:

```
jQuery("#course").on("select2-selecting", function (evt) {
  jQuery('#events-table tr.hidden-course').removeClass('hidden-course');
  jQuery('#events-table tr:not(".'+evt.val+'-event")').addClass('hidden-course');
  if (evt.val == '') {
    jQuery('#events-table tr').removeClass('hidden-course');
  }
});
```

Please let me know if this was helpful. If this successfully solves your issue, please mark that my answer "answered" your question.

Comment: Thanks, Anthony, but this only works for the first selections, once you select an option more than once the table remains blank.

Comment: Anthony, this worked after removing the space in the selector class - it should be "...tr.hidden ...", thanks!

Comment: Yes. You are correct about the space there. I will fix that in the answer above.

Glad to be of help!