# Custom filter inside Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Select2 has a query function. Whenever the search term changes, it runs the query function. The query function returns the filtered data.

I need to add two things:
1. I need to add radio buttons inside the Select2 to enable a quick filter
2. Whenever the radio value changes, i need to re-execute the query fn

[image: City selector component]

I have a hacky solution for 1. And I have not figured out 2.

For 1, I add a div containing radio buttons using the on-select2-open event. I append the div inside the .select2-drop.

For 2, I need a way to trigger the query function when the radio buttons are clicked.

Here is the HTML.

```
<form>
<input type='text' id='mySelId2' name='mySelName2' class='mySelClass2' style='width:300px;' value='101'/>
</form>

<div id='sel2-localcity-filter-tmpl-holder' style='display:none;'>
    <div class='sel2-localcity-filter'>
            <label>
            <input type="radio" onclick="CityFilter.onSel2FilterClick(this)" class='localcityFilter localcityFilter_No'
                name="localcityFilter" value="NoFilter" checked="checked" />Show all</label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label>
            <input type="radio" onclick="CityFilter.onSel2FilterClick(this)" class='localcityFilter localcityFilter_Local'
                name="localcityFilter" value="Local" >Only Australia</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mySelId2').select2({
        query: function(query){
            var res = { results: CityFilter.cities };
            query.callback(res);
        },
        initSelection: function(element, callback){
            var val = element.val();
            if(val==null) return;

            var data = null;
            for(var i=0;i<  CityFilter.cities.length;i++){
                if( CityFilter.cities[i].id==val){
                    data =  CityFilter.cities[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(data!=null){
                callback(data);
            }
        },
        formatResult: function(item){ return (item.name); },
        formatSelection: function(item){ return (item.name); },
        formatNoMatches: function(){ return '<span style="color:red;">No match</span>'; },
        dropdownCssClass: 'mySelClass2'
    });

    $('#mySelId2').on('select2-open', function(){
        var selClass = 'mySelClass2';
        var filterTemplateHolderId = 'sel2-localcity-filter-tmpl-holder';
        var filterTmpl = $('#' + filterTemplateHolderId).html();
        var existingFilterCount = $('.' +selClass+ '.select2-drop .sel2-localcity-filter').length;
        if(existingFilterCount==0){
            $('.' +selClass+ '.select2-drop').append(filterTmpl);
            $('.' +selClass+ '.select2-drop').unbind('click'); //This click handler prevents radio from working  //No I18n
        }
        $('.'+selClass+'.select2-drop').find('.localcityFilter_No').click();
    });
});

var CityFilter = {};
CityFilter.filterEnabled = false;
CityFilter.cities = [ {id:101, country:'NE', name:'Amsterdam'},
                        {id:102, country:'UAE', name:'Dubai'},
                        {id:103, country:'SW', name:'Bern'},
                        {id:104, country:'AUS', name:'Sydney'},
                        {id:105, country:'CAN', name:'Vancouver'},
                        {id:106, country:'NZ', name:'Auckland'},
                        {id:107, country:'AU', name:'Vienna'},
                        {id:108, country:'GER', name:'Munich'},
                        {id:109, country:'SW', name:'Zurich'},
                        {id:110, country:'AUS', name:'Melbourne'} ];
CityFilter.onSel2FilterClick = function(el){
    var jqRadio = $(el);
    if(jqRadio.val()=='Local'){
        CityFilter.filterEnabled = true;
    }else{
        CityFilter.filterEnabled = false;
    }
    console.log('CityFilter.filterEnabled: ' + CityFilter.filterEnabled);
};
```

Here is the JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/theomails/bw5s67js/1/

Comment: I found this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356396/how-to-filter-a-table-using-multiple-select2-boxes?rq=1. Adding a class to hide items in the results list will act as an 'AND' condition. i.e., When I click on radio i can add hide class. When typing is performed, i can filter results. They will work together to make sure minimum allowed items are visible.